# Couchbase 4.1 - N1QL by endpoint

Tags: scala, couchbase, sql++

I use Reactive Couchbase (this is Scala port for Java SDK - https://github.com/ReactiveCouchbase/ReactiveCouchbase-core)

And for query this use http endpoint (http:// mycouchbaseadress:8093 /query?q=N1QL Comand) but response for server is "Unrecognized parameter in request: q".

I Find in stackoverflow to start cbq-engine so try to launch 'cbq-engine -couchbase http:// mycouchbaseadress:8093 /' but have error ''flag provided but not defined: -couchbase"

My couchbase version is 4.1 community

Do you know how I can send my n1ql query to server by endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a bug in `ReactiveCouchbase`, or at least its N1QL support was developed against an outdated beta version of the feature.

With Couchbase Server 4.0 GA and above, you don't need to run `cbq-engine` (this was the process used during N1QL's beta).

The problem is that in the code, the `q=` parameter is used where it should now be `statement=` (or a JSON body).

There is a open [pull-request](https://github.com/ReactiveCouchbase/ReactiveCouchbase-core/pull/77) that happens to fix that issue among other things, but it's been opened a long time.